# Copy the content of ScalaCheck IntelliJ Tooltips

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I write scala code in IntelliJ. Sometimes IntelliJ shows me somethings which I can improve in my code. Ex

[image]

The moment i move my mouse the tooltip disappears.

This is very nasty because I can't copy the content of the tooltip into the clipboard and then google it.

I clicked on the event log windows of the IDE but even that doesn't show the content of the tooltip.

Any idea how I can copy the content into the clipboard?

I already tried Analyze -> Inspect code. even there the content of the tooltip in the screenshot is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Alt+Click to copy as described here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65636